# How to commit an object from a get controller to a post controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

how to transmit an object from a get controller to a post controller without using input fields on the jsp side?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/benutzerverwaltung/{benutzerID}/kennwort", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String BenutzerverwaltungKennwort(@PathVariable("benutzerID")int id, @ModelAttribute("benutzer") CBenutzer benutzer, Model model){
    benutzer.getBenutzer(id);
    benutzer.setPasswort(null);
    //code to transmit?
    return "benutzerverwaltung/kennwort";
}
```

and the second controller which should get the object benutzer

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/benutzerverwaltung/{benutzerID}/kennwort/aendern", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String BenutzerverwaltungKennwortGo(@PathVariable("benutzerID")int id, @ModelAttribute("benutzer") CBenutzer benutzer, Model model){
    //here I need the object with its attributes from the controller above...
    System.out.println(benutzer.toString()); //what i get is attributes = null -.-
    return "redirect:/benutzerverwaltung/";
}
```

Someone out there got an idea? thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use `HttpSession` attributes or flash attributes (which use the `HttpSession` anyway). To use flash attributes, Spring makes available the [`RedirectAttributes`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) class. In your GET handler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/benutzerverwaltung/{benutzerID}/kennwort", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String BenutzerverwaltungKennwort(@PathVariable("benutzerID")int id, @ModelAttribute("benutzer") CBenutzer benutzer, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){
    benutzer.getBenutzer(id);
    benutzer.setPasswort(null);
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("benutzer", benutzer);
    return "benutzerverwaltung/kennwort";
}
```

From the javadoc:

> After the redirect, flash attributes are automatically added to the
>   model of the controller that serves the target URL.

This will be true even if you didn't perform a redirect, ie. in the next request.

Note that these flash attributes are only available in the next request you make (flash!). If you aren't sure if the next request is the POST you need, you should save your object directly in the `HttpSession`.